# jquery mobile custom css trouble with a.class:hover

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am working with the jquery mobile framework 1.0 and I am attempting to implement a gradient background on the below a.grid-anchor with css :hover and can not seem to get it to work. This anchor is **NOT** using the jq mobile `data-role="button"`.

```
<div data-role="content">   

    <div id="ri-grid" class="ui-grid-c">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <a class="grid-anchor" href="#page2" data-transistion="slide">
                <div class="ui-bar rm-box border-br">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Sample text</li>
                        <li>more ttxt...</span></li>
                        <li><div class="icon-ir"></div></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>...</snip>
```

CSS:

```
a.grid-anchor:hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
}
```

*Using on safari only

Comment: It would be easier to help if there was a test case to look at. http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/

Comment: have you set anchor tag as block element?

Comment: @Jeffrey Gilbert - yes it is set to display: block. I will add a jsfiddle example per thirtydot's advice. Thank's guys!

Comment: @Jeffery Gilbert - *correction* a.grid-anchor { display: block !important; } produced expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to mobile framework, why would you try to use hover. is it possible to trigger that event on Hover via a mobile or touch screen? It is recommended not to use hover. Try some other events like on Mousedown or pointerdown events.